# How to configure jbpm6 with Mysql

Tags: mysql, gwt, jbpm

I want to  configure jbpm6 to work with Mysql, but there is no documentation for it.

I tried to change configuration files based on  Set up jBPM 5.4 Final Installer to use MySQL - or how to run section 3.7 of the User Guide

but in jbpm 6 package , some files is missed like :
1.task-service/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
2.lib/jbpm-human-task-war-5.4.0.Final-EE6.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml

after  changing  existing configuration files ,  ant install.demo  and then ant start.demo.db.noeclipse  run successfully but deploying of jbpm-console.war failed in jboss.

server.log on jboss contains these errors:

```
  15:13:57,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "jbpm-console.war"

15:14:17,067 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jbpmmigration-0.11.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,072 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry log4j-1.2.16.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jbpmmigration-0.11.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,090 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xercesImpl.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,099 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,108 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry serializer.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,125 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/serializer-2.7.1.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,140 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,149 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,159 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,169 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb1-impl.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,183 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,193 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry batik-all-1.7.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,201 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry commons-io-1.3.1.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,212 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry serializer-2.7.0.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,220 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry servlet-2.2.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,229 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xalan-2.7.0.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,238 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,247 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis-1.3.04.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,256 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,265 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xmlgraphics-commons-1.3.1.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,274 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry fop-hyph.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,283 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jai_codec.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,292 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jai_core.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,300 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jai_imageio.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,309 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jimi-1.0.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,318 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry xmlunit1.0.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/fop-0.95.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,330 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-api.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,339 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jaxb-impl.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,348 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry jsr173_1.0_api.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,358 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Class Path entry activation.jar in "/content/jbpm-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.

15:14:17,737 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'

15:14:17,747 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext,org.springframework.beans.BeansException' for service type 'org.apache.cxf.bus.factory'

15:14:17,762 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015893: Encountered invalid class name 'org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser,org.xmlpull.mxp1_serializer.MXSerializer' for service type 'org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory'

15:14:18,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for org.jbpm.domain

15:14:18,902 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.jbpm-console.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.netty:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.

15:14:18,927 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018567: Deployment "deployment.jbpm-console.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.netty:main") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.

15:14:19,292 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS016002: Processing weld deployment jbpm-console.war

15:14:20,223 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)

15:14:20,240 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)

15:14:20,256 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010402: Unable to instantiate driver class "org.h2.Driver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.jbpm-console_warorg_h2_Driver_1_3 is already registered

15:14:20,284 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)

15:14:20,303 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS016005: Starting Services for CDI deployment: jbpm-console.war

15:14:20,397 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-3) WELD-000900 1.1.5 (AS71)

15:14:20,537 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.KIE.TASK.#

15:14:20,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.TASK

15:14:20,592 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.KIE.TASK

15:14:20,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.TASK

15:14:20,611 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.TASK.ALL

15:14:20,621 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.KIE.SESSION.#

15:14:20,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.SESSION

15:14:20,649 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.KIE.SESSION

15:14:20,677 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.SESSION

15:14:20,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.SESSION.ALL

15:14:20,714 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-1) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.KIE.RESPONSE

15:14:20,723 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'TaskServiceRequesMessageBean' with 'hornetq-ra' resource adapter

15:14:20,722 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS014142: Started message driven bean 'KieSessionRequesMessageBean' with 'hornetq-ra' resource adapter

15:14:20,726 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.RESPONSE

15:14:20,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.RESPONSE.ALL

15:14:20,776 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server.impl.HornetQServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) trying to deploy queue jms.queue.KIE.RESPONSE.#

15:14:20,784 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.RESPONSE

15:14:20,799 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990

15:14:20,805 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 39633ms - Started 301 of 560 services (177 services failed or missing dependencies, 80 services are passive or on-demand)

15:14:21,001 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "jbpm-console.war" was rolled back with failure message JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete

15:14:21,065 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.TASK

15:14:21,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.SESSION

15:14:21,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.TASK

15:14:21,118 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.TASK.ALL

15:14:21,133 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.RESPONSE

15:14:21,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.RESPONSE.ALL

15:14:21,159 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/KIE.SESSION

15:14:21,169 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.SESSION.ALL

15:14:21,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011605: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:/queue/KIE.RESPONSE

15:14:21,835 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jbpm-console.war in 832ms

15:14:21,842 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => "JBAS014750: Operation handler failed to complete"}}
```

what else should I do to run jbpm6 by mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to manually edit the persistance files. The demo installer in jBPM6 has some property files that you can set before running ant install.demo. Try setting the db properties in the end of build.properties and then running ant.installdemo. There are sample values for MySQL commented out. Uncomment them, and commment out the H2 values.

Answer (score 0):

Files persistence.xml are in the db folder of your jbpm-installer.

You should change properties in jbpm-persistence-JPA2.xml